# Collada export breaks bones

Tags: export, bones, collada

I am trying to export a Model with a armature as .dae file to load it with Assimp into my game engine. The problem now is, Blender breaks the bones.

This is how it looks when I am exporting.

[image: exporting]

When I then start Blender again and try to import the dae again, I get this:

[image: broken]

In my game engine, which renders other animated.dae files perfectly fine, it looks like this:

[image: in game]

I am not sure where the issue is but I guess it's me being too dumb to use Blender correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googeling hours and hours i found out, Blenders Collada exporter is just buggy. For everyone who wants to use Blender and Assimp together i recommend the FBX file format. Both, Blender and Assimp do support it, you can configure Blenders FBX exporter to use the correct Coordinate-System (-z forwards, y upwards) and it even supports exporting all animations on the animation-stack as individual animations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. FBX works fine for me as well. The problem with Collada is that it duplicates some bones without any reason. Names are also the same, so the matrices are all mixed up

Answer (score 2):

I have found this add-on which fixes most Collada issues with Blender
https://github.com/godotengine/collada-exporter

Comment: This works for Xcode using SceneKit with Swift. If you use a texture, you need to change the Emission from White to Black.